# how to delete loadStatefulKnowledgeSession from db in jbpm5?(i.e Delete SESSIONINFO data from Database)

Tags: jbpm

My requirement is after loading the session from database and complete the all tasks then dispose session.Now in database  PROCESSINSTANCEINFO and WORKITEMINFO data were delete but still i have SESSIONINFO data so my question is how to delete SESSIOMINFO data ?

**Using strategy is Session per process instance.**